# SQL - finding the value between rows

Tags: sql, between

I have 2 tables:

- `Employee` table with 2 columns `Name` and `Sales`
- `Rewards` table with 2 columns `Bonus` and `Range`

Sample data:

```
Employee                     Rewards

| Name | Sales |             | Bonus | Range |
+------+-------+             +-------+-------+
| John | 112   |             | 2     | 200   |
| Mary | 201   |             | 3     | 300   |
| Joe  | 400   |             | 5     | 500   |
| Jack | 300   |
```

Each employee deserves bonus from the Rewords table if his sales <= Rewards.Range.

I want to select `Employee.Name` and `Rewards.Bonus`.

In this case the result should be:

```
| Name | Bonus |
+------+-------+
| John | 2     |
| Mary | 3     |
| Joe  | 5     |
| Jack | 3     |
```

Any idea what this SQL query will be?

Thanks,
zb

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Maybe this? `select name,bonus
  from Employee,Rewards
  where sales <= range
  group by name
  having min(range);
`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this approach.  There might be a syntax error or two.

```
select name
, (select bonus from rewards
where range =
(select min(range)
from rewards
where range >= sales)
)
from employee
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this one out and it retrieved the right results with your test tables:

```
SELECT   a.name,
         MIN(b.bonus) AS bonus
FROM db.employee a
INNER JOIN db.rewards b
ON a.sales <= b.range
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `lag` to get the bottom part part of each range and join it on the employee's table:

```
SELECT name, bonus
FROM   employee e
JOIN   (SELECT bonus, 
               range AS top_range,
               COALESCE(LAG(range) OVER (ORDER BY bonus ASC), 0) AS bottom_range
        FROM   rewards) r ON e.sales BETWEEN r.bottom_range AND r.top_range
```

Comment: As I understand BETWEEN means GREATER EQUAL from the bottom and LESS EQUAL from the top. When Sales = 200 it will fulfill conditions BETWEEN 0 AND 200 and BETWEEN 200 AND 300. Should I add "AND e.sales > r.bottom?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with OrderedBonuses as (
    select  e.name, r.bonus, row_number() over (partition by e.name order by r.Range desc) as ord
    from    Employee e
            JOIN Rewards r on e.Sales <= r.Range
)
select  name, bonus
from    OrderedBonuses
where   ord = 1;
```